# How to query nested field of object Y nested inside paginated objects X regarding the X objects?

Tags: go, graphql, schema, graphql-schema

I want to have a GraphQL schema like the following:

```
scalar Timestamp

input StatsArgs{
    start: Timestamp!
    end: Timestamp
}

input PaginationArgs{
    page: Int!
    limit: Int!
}

type Station{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    revenue(
        statsArgs: StatsArgs!
    ): Float!
}

type Product{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    stations: [Station!]!
}

type PaginatedProducts{
    pages: Int!
    total: Int!
    items: [Product!]!
}

type Shop{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
        stations: [Station!]!
    products(
        paginationArgs: PaginationArgs!
    ): PaginatedProducts!
}

type Query{
    shops(
            shopID: String
        ): [Shop!]
}

schema{
    query: Query
}
```

and query it like so:

```
query {
    shops {
        products(paginationArgs: { page: 1, limit: 20 }) {
            id
            name
            stations {
                id
                name
                revenue(statsArgs: { start: "2023-01-01", end: "2023-01-31" })
            }
         }
     }
}
```

The problem is that, using [gqlgen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen) and, probably, any other library in any language, it's difficult to make the server fetch the revenue of a station in regard to a product.

In order to make the server conscious that the client asks for the revenue of some station in regard to a product, I have 2 options:

- I make the productResolver.stations resolver ALWAYS fetch the revenue of a station in respect to each product
- I add a new Query field of the form `productStations(productIDs: [String!]!): [ProductStation!]!`

I want to avoid both of these solutions. The first is bad for performance and the second is just ugly and impractical.

What are any other possible solutions? I am open to suggestions regarding golang libraries (code generation is not required) or schema changes.